# How to make two camera pictures look similar (Brightness, White Balance,...)

Tags: opencv, camera, webcam, video-capture

I have two webcams (both are Logitech C615). I want to adjust the webcams in a way that they make nearly the same picture in same environment. (the reason is that I want to render this images onto an occulus rift).

I'm using OpenCV to connect the cameras. My first innocent try was to get all the CV_CAP_PROPs from the one cam and set the values to the other cam. That doesn't work very well.

Is there may already a function I could use or can you give me another approach?

--- EDIT: histogram equalization ---

That's the result:

[image]
The result is better than before but as you can see the hue is different.

Comment: Try histogram equalization: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_equalization/histogram_equalization.html

Comment: That seems to work only with grayscale images http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html#equalizehist

Comment: You can equalize each single channel of your image separately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to convert them to YCrCb and equalize just the Y channel (and convert them back to BGR if you need to).
This should equalize the brightness of both images.

Snippet:

```
cv::cvtColor( frame, frame, CV_BGR2YCrCb);
    cv::split( frame, channels);
cv::equalizeHist( channels[0], channels[0] );
    cv::merge( channels, 3, frame );
cv::cvtColor( frame, frame, CV_YCrCb2BGR );
```